# Calculating maximum value in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, modis, ndvi

I have MODIS NDVI data of four months and I have to calculate NDVImax.

I am using the Raster Calculator of ArcGIS and have been using various algorithms like [MAX ("june2000", "july2000" , "august2000", "september2000")] or [(MAX ("june2000", "july2000" , "august2000", "september2000")]

I tried the same in ERDAS Imagine with Global MAXIMUM function, of which i have attache an image, [image]but I am not able to get any results.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Fix title of your question, it is misleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the ArcGIS [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) tool for this type of analysis. Make sure to choose the "MAXIMUM" overlay statistic.

[image]